# Scroll not working after trigger click

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I am using `$$('.em-details-tabs')[0].scrollTo();` in a function and then trigger a click using `$$('DIVELEMENT')[0].click();`. The click function is executed successfully but the scroll to a specific element be failed. Here is my code snippet:

```
$$('a[href="#' + tab_id + '"]')[0].triggerEvent('click');
$$('.em-details-tabs')[0].scrollTo();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `scrollTo()` element is only available on the `window` object, and it also accepts two paramaters; `x` and `y` positions.

To fix this you can use jQuery's `scrollTop()` method on the `window` and provide it the `y` position of the required element. Try this:

```
$$('a[href="#' + tab_id + '"]')[0].triggerEvent('click');
$$(window).scrollTop($$('.em-details-tabs').offset().top);
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/cw49zjfm/)

Alternatively you can amend this logic to make the scroll animate so that the effect is obvious for your users:

```
$$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $$('.em-details-tabs').offset().top
}, 500);
```

[**Working Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/cw49zjfm/1)

Comment: Its working, But need two time press click , single click only tab open (clicked trigger fired) second time function call that time move (Scrolll) to appropriate postion,

Comment: I haven't seen that happen. Could you amend the fiddle examples above to show that behaviour

Comment: I am using prototype js and all scripts are

Comment: document.observe('click', function(e, el) {

Comment: if(el = e.findElement('#product-review-link')){
     if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    var url = $('product-review-link').href;
    window.location = url;
   }else{
    var tab_id = $('customer-reviews-top').up().identify();
    var placement = 'a[href="#'+tab_id+'"]';
    $$('a[href="#'+tab_id+'"]')[0].triggerEvent('click');
    $$('html, body').animate({
     scrollTop: $$('.em-details-tabs').offset().top
    }, 500);
    /* $$('.em-details-tabs')[0].scrollTo(); */
       e.stop();
   }

Comment: +++++++++++++++++   Issue part  (function portion) ++++++++

var tab_id = $('customer-reviews-top').up().identify();
    var placement = 'a[href="#'+tab_id+'"]';
    $$('a[href="#'+tab_id+'"]')[0].triggerEvent('click');
    $$('.em-details-tabs')[0].scrollTo();
       e.stop();